# How is array=(`echo "$@"`) different from array=$@ in bash?

Tags: bash

i'm new to bash. Could you, please, explain me difference between this code from tutor:

```
newarray=(`echo "$@"`)
```

and my line

```
newarray=$@
```

I would be very appreciate

Comment: Both of these are horrible. `newarray=$@` doesn't create an array at all; it creates a string, equivalent to `newarray=$*`. It would need to be `newarray=( "$@" )` to accurately copy `"$@"` into an array.

Comment: And ```newarray=( `echo "$@"` )``` is buggy as well -- if your program is run with `./yourprog "two words" "quoted * wildcard"`, it'll create very different/wrong results.

Comment: Compare `printf '%q\n' "$@"` and `printf '%q\n' "${newarray[@]}"` with the different formulations, if you want to compare their effects in practice. And find a better tutor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use either one. If you want another array consisting of the positional parameters, you should use

```
newarray=( "$@" )
```

To understand why, you need to understand

1. What `$@` does, and how it behaves when quoted.
2. What word splitting is, and when it is applied.
3. What pathname expansion is, and how it contributes to the first one being a bad idea.
4. How quoting works, so you know what does (or rarely, does not) need quoting.

All of the above is far too broad a topic to get into; I suggest reading (not just skimming) the `bash` man page. It's not great as a tutorial, but all the information you need is there.